# Troubleshooting .war file deployment

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, deployment, war

I have a .war file that will not deploy on either Eclipse 4.6 or Intellij IDEA 2016.1.3.

I'm using the proper version of Tomcat, and I've exhausted the related questions here.

Are there other common confounding problems with .war files? Are there alternatives to the two softwares I've already tried?

Comment: To save time for other people leaving suggestions, can you list specific StackOverflow questions that you have tried, along with any other things you tried.

Comment: Have you tried deploying it on tomcat normally and checked the logs for the exception without using Eclipse or IntelliJ